# Disabling MongoDB logging on Heroku/MongoHQ

Tags: mongodb, heroku, mongoid, mongohq

After getting the "logging negatively" warning, I guess ther's a way to disable on Heroku/MongoHQ too :

```
2011-10-02T05:35:38+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `thin -p 54227 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2011-10-02T05:35:44+00:00 app[web.1]: MongoDB logging. Please note that logging negatively impacts performance and should be disabled for high-performance production apps.
```

Does enybody know how to disable MongoDB logging on Heroku/MongoHQ ?

Thanks 
Luca

Comment: Which adapter/connector/ORM are you using?

Comment: MongoID, ... just added comment to your "good for me" answer :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess from the error message that you are using `Mongoid`. You can [disable the logger](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/734) by setting it to `nil`.

```
Mongoid.logger = nil
```

I believe there's also a way to set it to nil in the configuration block.

Comment: Thanks Simone, that was perfect ... I re-tagged +Mongoid - God Save the Italians -